# Camel routing from a ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: java, streaming, apache-camel, bytearrayinputstream

According to the [Camel Stream](http://camel.apache.org/stream.html) docs, it is possible to route message to/from various data streams.

However, in my case, I want the data (`byte[]`) in a `ByteArrayInputStream` to get sent off to a Camel route. The problem is that the only `InputStream` that component seems to support is `FileInputStream` like so:

```
from("stream:file?fileName=/server/logs/server.log&scanStream=true&scanStreamDelay=1000").to("bean:logService?method=parseLogLine");
```

But it looks like the only way to specify a `ByteArrayInputStream` is to use the `stream:header` URI like so:

```
ByteArrayInputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(someData);
from("direct:a").setHeader("stream", constant(byteStream)).to("stream:header");
```

But if you have to specify the custom stream as a header, I don't see how you could accomplish such a thing inside the `from()` clause. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stream:file` is for read files as a stream. You cannot send a java object to that endpoint. It only reads from files from your file system.

You can use Camel's type converter to convert the payload to something else, such as a `byte[]`

```
from("stream:file:...")
  .convertBodyTo(byte[].class)
  ...
```

You can read about Camel's type converter here: http://camel.apache.org/type-converter.html

Comment: How'd I send the byte stream to a file, equivalent to the Unix command `echo "hi" > somefile`?